# Effect on Session on UserName change?

Tags: session, weblogic, single-sign-on, webcenter, oam

I am using a OAM for access Management in my Application which is a WCP 11 PS4 A Application over Weblogic. 
One of the functionality in the application is allow the user to update/Change UserName within a logged In Session.

My Concern is when User updates username how will that affect Session. I believe though i am using the OAM (ObSSO Cookie) for authentication the container Session is Still maintained by the container and if session is Affected then will ObSSO Cookie also needs to be updated accordingl

Answer (score 0):

When the user(assuming uid) changed in the logged in session the ObSSOCookie will not be affected but the other use-cases like logout or OAM Session timeout will be affected. Ideally you should regenerate the ObSSOCookie for updated/changed user.

Comment: Thanks Anil that was helpful. My main concern is if I update Obsso Cookie and after updateing if i invoke lets say  something like FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap() will the session Map returned be same as old or a new session is created all together.

Comment: It will return the new session.